# How can you enable transactions with IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries for stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to write a client which executes a series of DB2 iSeries Stored procedures in DB2. I am using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries  provider and need all my calls to be within a .NET transaction. Seems like everything is ignored and data being committed.Any pointers...

Answer (score 3):

Is the database on the iSeries journaled?  That's required for commitment control.

Comment: Is your iSeries server under software maintenance?  If so you can probably call IBM and ask them directly.

Comment: Also it might be helpful to know how those stored procedures are defined or used.  Are you using the SQL CALL statement, are they RPG programs, etc.

Comment: BTW stored procedures can be defined to auto-commit when they are used.  See the second to last paragraph at http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg061604-story01.html.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue, and figured out that the problem is not in the .Net code, but in the stored procedure.  Check your stored proc definition for a COMMIT option.  If it is set to "*NONE" it will auto-commit, regardless of transactions in your .Net code.  Change it to *RR (repeatable read), and your transactions should work correctly.

More information [here](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg012407-story01.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [DB2Connection.BeginTransaction Method?](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.dndp.doc/htm/frlrfIBMDataDB2DB2ConnectionClassBeginTransactionTopic.htm)